# Connotazione negativa del termine “extracomunitario”

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Treccani, come tutti gli altri dizionari, da le seguenti definizioni del termine:

***extracomunitario***;

> - agg. e s. m. [comp. di extra- e comunitario (cfr. comunità, n. 2 a)]. – Che non fa parte dell’Unione Europea: paesi e,
> - come sost., spec. al plur. masch., gli e., coloro che emigrano da paesi economicamente disagiati (spec. da regioni dell’Africa e dell’Asia) negli stati dell’Unione Europea in cerca di lavoro e di migliori condizioni di vita.

La seconda definizione, con connotazione spesso negativa, è senza dubbio la più comune e diffusa nel linguaggio contemporaneo. Ad esempio:

da [Parlarecivile.it:](http://www.parlarecivile.it/argomenti/immigrazione/extracomunitario.aspx)

> L’uso discriminatorio del termine è stato sancito in un atto ufficiale. A Savona il procuratore capo Francantonio Granero ha cancellato questa parola da tutti gli atti giudiziari con una circolare del 7 settembre 2011, ***chiedendo alla polizia giudiziaria la sostituzione di ‘extracomunitario’ con altre espressioni non offensive nei confronti dei cittadini stranieri***.

Da [IlGiornale.it](http://www.ilgiornale.it/news/politica/clandestini-zingaro-parole-vietate-sentenza-1368514.html):

> La dittatura linguistica delle toghe ha rifatto la sua comparsa due giorni fa, quando ha condannato la Lega Nord per aver usato il termine clandestini, ritenuto «denigratorio» e «discriminatorio»......***Lo stesso vale per le parole africano, marocchino ed extracomunitario.***

Quando e perché il termine comincia ad essere impropriamente usato fino a diventare, per alcuni, un'offesa?

Comment: Grazie per aver riformulato la domanda sostenendola con qualche fonte. In particolare, il sito “Parlare civile” sembra interessante e forse può essere un punto di partenza anche per una risposta.

Comment: se posso abbozzare un'ipotesi, credo che l'inizio possa essere rintracciato almeno al 2002, quando la legge c.d. Bossi-Fini introduce il termine (non presente nella precedente legge c.d. Turco-Napolitano, ma già presente nella c.d. legge Martelli), ed alla polemiche relative alla sua approvazione

Answer (score 1):

Non penso sia possibile datare con esattezza il momento in cui il termine ha assunto un termine denigratorio, spesso omologato al concetto di migrante/africano/"negro".

Tecnicamente, il termine inizia a circolare dopo il 26 marzo 1995, in cui fu approvata la libera circolazione delle persone nella UE; non ho ricordo di uso del termine prima di allora. E laddove "comunitario" assunse immediatamente un'accezione positiva (legato forse alla parola "comunità"), extracomunitario assunse rapidamente un aspetto negativo.

In realtà, "extracomunitario" si applicherebbe a tutti coloro che non fanno parte della UE, quindi anche a svizzeri, norvegesi, statunitensi e (presto) britannici, ma nel parlare comune si usa in un senso più ristretto, denigratorio e sbagliato. Un po' come il termine "marocchino" che nella pianura padana degli anni 70-80 era un termine denigratorio nei confronti dei meridionali.